# Show that the set of values of $w$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

Let $f(x,w,v)$ and $g(x,w,v)$ two polynomial functions (in $x$) with integer coefficients with $x>a$ is an integer variable and $a>0$. Here $w,v$ are also integer variables. Assuming that the degree of $f$ and $g$ are equal and greater than or equal $1$. Let us consider the following **implicit equation**:

$$w=f(x,w,v)/g(x,w,v)$$  **holds** for all $x>a$.

Then my **question** is: Show that the set of values of $w$ is finite.

My **solution**:

From this link: https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/eventually-bounded-rational-functions.138510/, it is possible to conclude that the function $x→f(x,w,v)/g(x,w,v)$ is bounded and hence the set of values of $w$ is finite.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @TSF: Show that the set of values of $w$ is finite.

Comment: @TSF: Then it is necessary to assume that the degree is $>1$.

Comment: That doesn't matter.

Comment: @TSF: So additional conditions are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true. Let $f(x,w,v) = wx^n$ and $g(x,w,v) = x^n$. The degree of $f$ and $g$ as polynomials of $x$ are equal (both $n$). The implicit equation is $w=w$ which holds for all integer $w$ for all $a\geq 0$ for all $x>a$. The set of values for $w$ is then infinite.